# Bootstrap overrides my own CSS rules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap for my project, and for some unknown reason it keeps overwriting over my CSS rules.

I included my CSS file **after** the bootstrap css files, and still it doesn't help.

Why does it happens?

And no, I don't want to use `!important` each time...

[Example of my code](http://pastebin.com/6L2AmHp3)

Comment: Which CSS is getting overridden ? Can you post CSS of Bootstrap and your own ?

Comment: Have they used !important in the boot strap css?

Comment: @Alok http://pastebin.com/6L2AmHp3

Comment: @DanCundy No, I've attached an example code

Comment: CSS looks fine, Try to see the line numbers of each in inspect element and check why the bootstrap code comes after your own CSS.

Comment: @Alok Tried that, but still cant find out why it happens...

Comment: Share us the screenshot of CSS inspect. May be we could help. Make sure you share full height of inspect screen.

Comment: Have you validated that your file paths are correct? If your css is included after the bootstrap css and it's more specific than the bootstrap css, then maybe the file cannot be found.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue. And it seems to be selective (i.e., some items are overridden while some are not).